# Ошибка SSL сертификата при отправке GET запроса в Telegram Bot

Tags: java, telegram-bot, kotlin, mongodb, ssl

Пишу бота для телеграмма, понадобилось перевести БД (MongoDB) в облако. Платформа, на которой я её разместил подразумевает защиту SSL сертификатом. Долго с этим провозился, но в итоге получилось.

Чтобы использовать сертификат у меня прописано

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "C:/Users/krugl/.mongodb/mongostore")
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "password")
```

Подключаюсь к БД строкой

```
KMongo.createClient("mongodb://user:password@HOSTADRESS:PORT/BOTNAME?ssl=true")
```

И все работает. Но когда я пытаюсь отправить боту GET запрос для смены webhook

```
val url =
        URL("https://api.telegram.org/bot${mySuperTelegramBot.botToken}/setWebhook?url=${conf.webHookPath}")
    val con = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
    con.requestMethod = "GET"
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json")
    con.connectTimeout = 1000
    con.readTimeout = 1000
    con.inputStream
    con.disconnect()
```

Или отправить пользователю сообщение методом execute() мне выдает ошибку

```
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Как я понимаю, что отправке этих запросов мешает сертификат, который я использую для подключения к БД, но как сделать, чтобы они не конфликтовали, я не понимаю.

Comment: Может все-таки keyStore вам нужен? https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/adminguide/cadminsslclient.html

Comment: Для keystone ведь нужен файл .key, или .pkcs12. У меня имеется только сертификат CA.pem и root.crt

Comment: Вопрос не совсем в этом. Вы проверяете сертификат сервера или он ваш? Я подозреваю что второе. Тогда вам нужен keyStore и сертификат с приватным ключем.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja Вот такая инструкция для подключения на [сайте](https://cloud.yandex.ru/docs/managed-mongodb/operations/connect), там используют trustStore

Comment: @Eugene Krivenja Плюс подключение к Mongo работает, следовательно сертификат проверяется правильно, и запросы к БД отправляются и ответы получаю. Перестают работать запросы к telegram api https://api.telegram.org/bot

Comment: С Монго все выглядит верно, проблема только в том, что Яндекс использует собственный СА, поэтому приходится его дополнительно прописывать. Но тот путь, что они предлагают достаточно грубый, потому что вы заменяете системное хранилище сертификатов своим, который содержит только один CA. Вот все остальное HTTPS и перестает работать. Смотрите вот тут: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49779310/5479247

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Благодаря комментариям Eugene Krivenja у меня получилось решить проблему, действительно  хватило того, чтобы удалить созданный мной trustStore и добавить сертификат в базовый trustStore java

В PowerShell командой

```
\keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore C:\pathToJDK\lib\security\cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -alias yourAliasName -file path\to\certificate.crt
```